# Editing xlsx files in place

Tags: julia

I'm using the XLSX.jl package. I want to make small changes to simple existing worksheets - updating a single cellvalue, for instance. At present, I can do this successfully using XLSX.openxlsx with mode=rw but it looks likely that the rw option will soon be retired.

My next option was to use XLSX.readxlsx, make changes, and then write the changed version using XLSX.writexlsx. This doesn't seem to work for me, and I wonder if anyone can help me understand why.

My first, failed, attempt just tried to read and then write an xlsx file without making any changes:

```
using XLSX

xf = XLSX.readxlsx("Dummy1.xlsx")
println(typeof(xf))
println(XLSX.sheetnames(xf))
XLSX.writexlsx("testXLSX.xlsx", xf)
```

The output is below. The last line of this code generated the error:

```
XLSX.XLSXFile
["Mock-up", "Document History"]
ERROR: LoadError: AssertionError: XLSXFile instance is not writable.
Stacktrace:
 [1] writexlsx(output_source::String, xf::XLSX.XLSXFile; overwrite::Bool)
   @ XLSX C:\Users\TGebbels\.julia\packages\XLSX\we7i6\src\write.jl:62
 [2] writexlsx(output_source::String, xf::XLSX.XLSXFile)
   @ XLSX C:\Users\TGebbels\.julia\packages\XLSX\we7i6\src\write.jl:60
 [3] top-level scope
```

Have I missed something basic? Are there any specific limitations on the content of an xlsx file that XLSX.writexlsx can write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files opened via `openxlsx` are loaded in non-writable mode.

```
julia> xf = XLSX.openxlsx(raw"c:\temp\Book1.xlsx");

julia> xf.is_writable
false
```

Use the `mode="rw"` parameter as described in https://felipenoris.github.io/XLSX.jl/stable/tutorial/#Writing-Excel-Files:

```
xf = XLSX.openxlsx(raw"c:\temp\Book1.xlsx", mode="rw")
@assert xf.is_writable
```

Or use `open_xlsx_template` instead (both call the same internal function):

```
xf = XLSX.open_xlsx_template(raw"c:\temp\Book1.xlsx");
@assert xf.is_writable
```

Now you can do:

```
XLSX.writexlsx(raw"c:\temp\Book2.xlsx", xf)
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes, that does the trick.  Did I miss it in the XLSX API?

Comment: I found it writing `xf.is_writable=true` and than trying to write the file and also looking at the source code :)

Comment: Sleuthing like that is hard for novices like me.  Thank goodness for experts like you!

Comment: So actualyl it is documented in the tutorial: https://felipenoris.github.io/XLSX.jl/stable/tutorial/#Writing-Excel-Files   :)

Comment: I cannot find any reference to `XLSX.open_xlsx_template` in the tutorial or the API, I'm afraid. Is it just me?